# partition a list based on a text in the file name

Tags: scala

I have a list which contains file names. I want to partition the list based on a text in the file name.

```
val files = List("/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_01.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_02.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_reg_01.txt", "/mnt/tmp/abc_reg_02.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_03.txt")
```

i want to create 2 list with one contains files which has **reg** in its name and one which contains **agg** in its name.

Output

```
val reg_files = List("/mnt/tmp/abc_reg_01.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_reg_02.txt")
val agg_files = List("/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_01.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_02.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_03.txt")
```

How can I create these 2 lists?

Comment: these are the only 2 file names we will get! although i would be curious if any other file names would be there then it would be in a 3rd list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val files = ...
val (regs, noRegs)   = files.partition(_ contains "_reg_")
val (aggs, badFiles) = noRegs.partition(_ contains "_agg_")
```

But let's make it a little more interesting. Let's give those 3 letters between the underscores a name. Let's call that the file's "tag". And we want lists of all the file names with the same tag, but we don't know how many different tags are in the `files` list.

```
val pttrn = ".*_(...)_\\d+.txt".r
val fmap =
  files.foldRight(Map[String,List[String]]().withDefaultValue(Nil)){
    case (fn@pttrn(tag), acc) => acc + (tag -> (fn :: acc(tag)))
    case (fn,            acc) => acc + ("xx" -> (fn :: acc("xx")))
  }
```

Every tag encountered becomes a key in the resulting `fmap`, and every value is the list of file names with that tag.

File names that don't fit the pattern are collected under the `"xx"` key.

Comment: thanks the first command worked...will try the other commands mentioned!

Comment: Why not just using `partitionMap` and `collect` or `filter` before to remove bad files.

Answer (score 0):

```
val files = List("/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_01.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_02.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_reg_01.txt", "/mnt/tmp/abc_reg_02.txt","/mnt/tmp/abc_agg_03.txt")

val (reg, agg, other) = files.foldLeft((List.empty[String], List.empty[String], List.empty[String])) { case((l1, l2, l3), name) =>
  if (name.contains("_reg_")) (name :: l1, l2, l3)
  else if (name.contains("_agg_")) (l1, name :: l2, l3)
  else (l1, l2, name :: l3)
}
```